# Updating specific class in Java

Tags: java, class, object

If I initialize classes like this:

```
square s = new square(1,2,'$');
square s = new square(2,4,'$');
square s = new square(3,2,'$');
square s = new square(5,4,'$');
```

is there any way to "get back" the class I initialized with `(1,2,'$')`? Other than giving it a variable name of course, I would like to not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't compile because of the same variable names. I guess you're looking for arrays.

```
square[] s = new square[4];

s[0] = new square(1,2,'$');
s[1] = new square(2,4,'$');
s[2] = new square(3,2,'$');
s[3] = new square(5,4,'$');
```

You can then refer the first `square` object with `s[0]`.

As an aside, you should name your class in upper camel case i.e. `Square`. Take a look at the Java naming conventions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for. Yes I know the naming is not good, got a little lazy there.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no. 
Longer answer: once you give up a reference in Java, it's lost to you and will be garbage collected. However, there's no reason you can't make a new object with the same parameters.

Side note: those four lines could never compile, since you can't redeclare `s` after declaring it in the same context.

Even more detail: if you remove the redeclarations, what's happening here is this: Calling the constructor for `square` (using the `new` operator) creates a new instance, and returns the address of that instance, which is stored in `s`. When you assign a new value to `s`, the old one is lost - and since you haven't had a chance to store that old reference anywhere else, the instance that you created previously is now dead, in the sense that nothing can point to it. That means that the garbage collector will find it the next time that it comes around, and its space on the heap will be reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

The reference is lost and thus collected automatically via the [garbage collector](http://javabook.compuware.com/content/memory/how-garbage-collection-works.aspx). The only thing you can do is initialise another variable and passing the same arguments.

If you wish to describe what you're trying to do exactly go ahead, we may help further.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code won't compile.

This will compile:

```
square s = new square(1,2,'$');
s = new square(2,4,'$');
s = new square(3,2,'$');
s = new square(5,4,'$');
```

If this is what you meant, there is no way to get back to the first square because you have reused the pointer s.
Anyway, take a look at the [Memento Pattern](http://square%20s%20=%20new%20square(1,2,'$');%20square%20s%20=%20new%20square(2,4,'$');%20square%20s%20=%20new%20square(3,2,'$');%20square%20s%20=%20new%20square(5,4,'$');)